# Examples for Ermakoff's convergence test.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

There are several convergence tests (Ratio, Root, Direct comparison, Integral, etc). When one test is inconclusive, another more powerful one (or a combination of tests) is used.

For example, the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln n}{n^2}$ (Bertrand series) is inconclusive by Ratio and Root tests, but is proved by the Comparison test ($\ln n\le \sqrt{n}$). Or it can be tested by Integral test (by integration by parts). Or it can be tested by Ermakoff's test (see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ErmakoffsTest.html) or [here](http://pm-pu.ru/stuff/analiz/books/demidovich_sbornik.pdf) (in Russian, page $257$, Q.$2624$)):

$$\lim_\limits{x\to\infty}\frac{e^xf(e^x)}{f(x)}=\lim_\limits{x\to\infty}\frac{e^x\cdot \frac{x}{e^{2x}}}{\frac{\ln x}{x^2}}=\lim_\limits{x\to\infty}\frac{x^3}{e^x\ln x}=0<1.$$
Now my question is: can a series be made so that the Comparison and Integral tests are very difficult and  the Ermakoff's test is advantageous?

Comment: it's quite hard to find something difficult for the comparison test, considering most Ermakoff problems involve logarithms, which are relatively easy to compare. however, $$  \sum \frac{\ln n}{n \ln \ln n} $$ can be solved via Ermakoff, the integral test is useless because of the exponential integral.

Comment: The Comparison Test is not a by  a specific formula. If $|a_n|\leq |b_n|$  for all $n$ and you already know that $ \sum_n|b_n|$  converges then you know that $\sum_na_n$ converges. So the degree of difficulty of the Comparison Test depends on what catalog of known absolutely convergent series is available to you.